# Ember.js: Save a record in the local store from DS.RESTAdapter

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have an adapter that retrieves records from a JSON API:

```
    App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        find: function() {
            var url = 'I MAKE AN AJAX CALL TO THIS URL WITH JSONP AND IT RETURNS JSON CONTAINING MANY OBJECTS I WANTED TO SAVE IN THE STORE'; 
            return $.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
                return data.map(function(result) {
                    var newPost = store.createRecord('post', {
                        title:   result.title,
                        content: result.content
                    });
                    newPost.save();
                })
            })
        }
    })
```

I have tried many ways but I simply could not get the store reference there (I already set up the post model). Also, I'm not even sure if it is the correct/recommended way to do this (Fetch the json from API and save it as soon as it is retrieved). I think it could work if I do this in the PostRoute but does it break the convention?

Comment: What you are trying to do is conceptually wrong. What usually happens is, `store` passes the control to `adapter` when it necessary to perform network operations, and adapter's responsibility is to perform those operations and return records in required format. **What is your actual issue?** This seems like an [X,Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @code-jaff I was fetching every single post through the adapter so it would have to access the internet on every request, and nothing was saved to the local store. So I was trying to figure out how to fetch all the posts all at once and save them to the local store so that it would be much more responsive when switching to other posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to properly extend the RestAdapter, I suggest you look at the source code for reference.

RestAdapter.find: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L330

RestAdapter.ajax : https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L749